# Excel table not expanding when new data is added

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains four data tables on the same tab. The final 3 columns in each contain formulae.

I then have a vba code which performs an sql look up within an SQL Server table and returns a set number of columns to update each of the four tables.

For three of these tables, the data is pasted in and the table automatically expands and the formulae is copied to the end of the table.

However, for the first table, the data is pasted in but the table does not expand and hence, the formulae does not get added to the rows outside of the table.

I have searched high and low for a fix but no joy. I have searched the data extraction VBA code with no luck (the code is an exact match) and no joy in the table properties. I have also checked the Options menu for Auto Format As You Type settings but all seems fine.

Does anyone have any ideas for me?

Thanks,

David.

Hi All again,

Would love to know if anyone has an answer for this but, in the mean time I have fudged the code to automatically adjust the size of the table based on the row number for the last cell of data.

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and it was driving me nuts.  Found out that in a few columns I had dragged formulas down pretty far (they were IF statements to return nothing if the first column was empty) so I didn't see them.

So remove any formulas that are 'under' the last row of the table.  Should clear up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is due to differing number of, or mis-aligned columns (vertically stacked tables) or differing number of, or mis-aligned rows (horizontally stacked tables).

For simplicity, let us use vertically stacked tables to illustrate what is happening.  Consider an upper table with 2 columns and a lower table with 3.  If we try to insert a row to the upper table, XL attempts to push all cells beneath the table down, but ONLY the cells directly beneath the table.  So in this case cells below the 2 columns will be pushed down.  XL quickly realizes that if it pushes just 2 columns down, the third column in the lower table won't be pushed down resulting in skewing the lower table.  XL makes no attempt to figure out how to move the lower tables. It just refuses to even try.

The same holds true for adding columns to tables on the left for which there are tables directly to the right.  If adding columns to a table would result in skewing rows of a table to the right, XL refuses to help.

To keep this from being a problem we can do a few things:

- Keep the largest tables on top and to the left and align all table first columns and first rows.
- If only rows are added to tables, don't stack them vertically
- And if only columns are added to tables, don't stack them horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith is an example of enforcing expansion of a table after data was copied over to the bottom of the table. This is done by resizing the table. Originally the table wasn't auto-resized as it has additional calculation columns.
The first line of the code finds the last row of data and the second line states the range to which the table needs to be resized. The third line resizes the table to the new range.
Replace sXXX and tXXX with your sheet name and table name.

```
Sub ResizeTableXXX()
    myLastrowOfData = sXXX.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    myNewRangeSize = "$A$5:$P$" & myLastrowOfData
    sXXX.ListObjects("tXXX").Resize Range(myNewRangeSize)
End Sub
```

HIH